# Relationship - 3 tables relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a relationship through of 3 tables.

My relationship - USER -> ANSWER -> QUESTION

Answer Model

```
public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question','id');
    }
```

Question Model

```
 public function answer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question','question_id');
    }
```

User Model

```
  public function maritalStatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Answer','marital_status');
    }
```

View

```
{{ $user->maritalStatus->question->label }}
```

Error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$label

Thank You

Comment: A answer has many questions but a question has only (belongs to) a single answer? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: An answer has a single question. But a quesiton has many answers.

Comment: Your model show something different. Also, your `answer` function in your `Question` model actually belongs to a `Question`, not to an `Answer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the relations interchanged.

Here's what would make sense to me: `Answer belongsTo Question` and `Question hasMany Answer`.

```
class Answer
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

}



class Question
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }

}
```

As in your case, `$answer->question` is a collection (not a single model) because you defined it as a `hasMany` relation instead of a `belongsTo`.

So if you want to keep your relations the way you have them now (which i don't expect, as an answer that answers many questions at a time is quite rare compared to the opposite), you'd need to add for example a `->first()` to your `{{ $user->maritalStatus->question->first()->label }}`. But in that case, rather call it `questions` (plural), then its probably more obvious…

Comment: Thanks. You helped me alot.